# How to force error_reporting mode in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, deprecated, ioncube

I have some code that's encrypted with ioncube and it's also written for < PHP 5.3. There's a ton of deprecated code, which would still work, but there's error messages all over the site.

Is there a way of externally forcing error_reporting to E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED or similar? I'm sure in the code they're hardcoding to E_ALL for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolled back to PHP 5.2 and avoided the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable `display_errors` and log them to a file instead. That is standard procedure for any production web site.

In an Apache config file, `php_admin_value error_reporting X` should make it impossible to be overridden by user code, where `X` is the integer value you want.

Also, `set_error_handler()` might be of use if you want to do some runtime checks.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I've tried adding php_admin_value error_reporting 22519 (which is the int value of E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED) to my httpd.conf under the virtualhost section.

I can see it working though. If I run a phpinfo() then error_reporting shows up as I specify in the local value. It seems though that the error_reporting function overrides php_admin_value (where ini_set can't).

Comment: I think the application I'm using already sets an error handler. I ended up rolling back to PHP 5.2 so the application would work. Thanks for your help anyway.